# How can I add these two tables to display value from both in laravel?

Tags: laravel

How can I add these two tables to display value from both in laravel?

**Module table:**

```
id | code | semester | name | description | lecturer_id
```

**Examination Table:**

```
id | module_id | name | startdate | enddate | duration | type | code | status
```

**I want to display these:**

```
ModuleCode | ModuleName | Title | Date | Type | Duration | Code | Status
```

**But I am getting these:**

```
Title | Date | Type Duration | Code | Status | Action
```

**What I tried:**

```
$examinations =  DB::table('modules')
                  ->select('modules.name as modulename', 'modules.code as modulecode')
                  ->leftjoin('examination', 'modules.id', '=', 'examination.module_id')
                  ->get();

$examinations = Examination::select('examination.name', 'examination.startdate', 'examination.enddate', 'examination.duration', 'examination.type', 'examination.code', 'examination.status', 'examination.id')
                 ->leftjoin('modules', 'modules.id', '=', 'examination.module_id')->get();

$examinations = Module::join('examination',  'modules.id', '=',  'examination.module_id')
                 ->select('modules.name as modulename', 'modules.code as modulecode', 'examination.name', 'examination.startdate',
```

Comment: look into the eloquent orm; it  remedies these verbose queries, just as a note.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module::select([
   'modules.code as ModuleCode, 
   'modules.name as ModuleName,
   'examination.name as Title',
   'examination.startdate as Date',
   'examination.type as Type',
   'examination.duration as Duration',
   'examination.code as code',
   'examination.status as Status', 
'])->join('examination', 'modules.id', '=', 'examination.module_id')->get();
```

Use `leftJoin` if there might not be an examination for the module but you still want the data from Module. If you want to see the data only with examination, use `join`.

Comment: with left join only status values are outputted